# 8-month-old wants to eat in the night but won't take milk

Tags: infant, feeding, night-time

Our 8-month-old girl eats lots - she's almost completely weaned because she has no interest in breast or formula milk during the day. She has breast milk once a night at the moment but my supply is almost gone and she frequently needs more at night. She won't take a bottle (she did during the day for a while but never has at night and doesn't during the day now either) but is definitely hungry rather than waking for another reason (I can hear her tummy rumbling just holding her). I can spend an hour or more feeding her solid food in the evening just stuffing more and more in but it never seems to satisfy her past midnight (and that's a really good night. Sometimes she's awake by 9 or 10).

Her weight is a little on the high side but not massively and she's recently been ill which ramped this up even worse temporarily, but seems to have died back to normal levels of crazy.

What do I feed her? At the moment I grab whatever I can get my hands on easiest in the middle of the night but I'd rather she have something healthy. I also need something I can pre-prepare before bed and that's quick and easy to feed her with little to no light and minimal mess.

Comment: What food does she eat during the day? Some cooked veggies waiting ready in the fridge come to mind, but "little mess", "no bottle" and "8 months" sounds like a hard thing to have all at once.

Comment: She will eat pretty much anything she's given - she's adept at finger food and lumpy spoon fed food. Tbh something that's quick to feed to her is more important than the mess - I can sort mess out in the morning if I'm not massively sleep deprived. She'd probably be quite slow with cooked veggies and pouches of veg puree don't seem to fill her up for long.

Comment: Will she drink milk from a cup rather than from a bottle?

Comment: Yes but only in smalll sips - no where near enough to get a full milk feed into her in any sensible length of time.

Comment: What's her bedtime -- i.e., how long is she sleeping before waking up hungry? I'm not trying to be nitpicky with all my questions, just making sure there's plenty of detail for somebody to write an answer :)

Comment: No worries about being nitpicky- anything that helps! She normally has dinner starting at 5.40, eats solidly until about 6.15 then I get a 15 min break and she eats again from 6.30 till about 6.50 then bed by about 7pm. She is often awake by 10pm though sometimes goes till 12 or 1am if I'm very lucky.

Comment: We found ours would only take a bottle at night if it was really warm - at the higher end of the recommended range. At first it worried us but it really worked.

Comment: I don't want to be "that person" but... have you spoken to her pediatrician about this? If so, what advice did they have? Surely they would be able to suggest some calorie-dense but healthy foods.

Comment: I'm in the UK so it's a little bit different. The Health Visitors are the ones to go to for this but unfortunately they are largely unhelpful as they only give the officially sanctioned advice which is nothing but breast, bottle or water at night.

Comment: I'm wondering if you are feeding her too much solid food, when what she needs is calorie-dense breastmilk/formula.

Comment: Is she taking water or other drinks?  If she won't take a bottle, perhaps a sippy cup or even a weighted straw cup.  It seems to me that she may not be taking enough liquids, which can also cause her to wake up from thirst.

Would you consider offering her milk in some kind of cup even during the day so she gets better at drinking it that way?

Edit:  If she really only wants solids, could you feed her something like oatmeal or porridge made with breastmilk or formula?  That's possibly one way to more of the proper nutrients into her.

Answer (score 1):

For all three of ours we gave them a bottle of formula last thing at night so that I could help with feeding and give my wife a rest. A nice side effect of formula is that it takes a lot longer to digest so the kids really slept through once they had fed.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of something called a supplemental nursing system?  You can put formula into it, then there is a tube that you run to your nipple, so if she is willing to latch, she can nurse it through that tiny tube.  It works for many babies that do bottle refusal, though I find them a tad more hassle of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little concerned that your healthcare provider doesn't see a problem with this. At that age, breasts milk or formula should be your daughter's primary source of food. Could you get referred to a nutritionist? I think it's important to make sure your daughter has all the nutrients she needs for her growth.

For one thing, fat is very important for young children's brain development. Milk supplies enough fat but it is most of the time missing from the solid diet we feed babies. If you are giving her dairy, like yogurt or cottage cheese, make sure that it is made from whole milk (aim for the fattest you can find). Proteins are also very important and longer to digest, so they will make her feel full for longer. You could try to feed proteins to her at night (chicken, fish, tofu, etc.)

I'm sure you tried many things, but we had great success with sippy cups for our breastfed baby who wouldn't take a bottle. There are ones for 6 months+ With handles which he was able to hold himself. Keep experimenting with different sippy cups and formulas, and you might find something she likes.